# Proving Probability of An Asymptotic Relation of a Combinatoric Function

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

First, define $S(X,Y)$ as the number of (potentially-noncontiguous) occurrences of $Y$ as a subsequence in $X$, where $X$ and $Y$ are Q-ary sequences of lengths $n$ and $k=n\Theta$, respectively where $\Theta\in(0,1)$. For example when $Q=2$, $X=101101$ and $Y=011$, we have $S(X,Y)=3$

I am interested in the distribution of this function $S(X,Y)$ when $X$ is an i.i.d. uniform sequence of length $n$ and $Y$ is a uniformly chosen (potentially-noncontiguous) subsequence of length $k$ of $X$. I would like to investigate the distribution and/or the moments **conditioned on the fact that $Y$ is a subsequence of $X$**.

I can calculate or bound the probabilities of the extreme individual scenarios, like $P(S(X,Y)=1)$ and $P(S(X,Y)=\binom{n}{k})$ which are the probabilities of the two extreme cases.

For example, trivially I find a bound on the worst-case probability
$P(S(X,Y)=\binom{n}{k})\le Q^{(1-n)}$

Most importantly, the fact even in the worst case scenario, we have $\binom{n}{k}\le 2^{n H_b(\frac{k}{n})}$ and simulation results I obtained have led me to think that for some alphabet size $Q=\omega(n^2)$ we should have an alphabet size $Q$ for which there must be a lower bound of the following form:

$$P(\log S(X,Y)=o(n))\ge 1-c_1 Q^{-c_2 n+o(n)}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

Independent of whether my hunch is true or not, how can I prove the probability of such an order relation, when the counting function depends greatly on the realization?

Comment: If $Y$ is uniformly chosen among subsequences of size $k$ of $X$, then $S(X,Y)\ge 1$ always holds, right? Why did you add the conditioning?

Comment: Yes, it always holds. I introduced the condition to stress the fact that $Y$ is already a subsequence. In the literature this function is investigated when $Y$ is independent of $X$. To simply use the same notations and definitions without any confusion, I allowed one to consider $Y$ as independent of $X$ by adding the constraint.

Comment: You don't get the same distribution when you pick $Y$ as a random subsequence of $X$, or when you pick $Y$ as a random sequence and then condition on the event "$Y$ is a subsequence of $X$". The first one will be more biased towards sequences that appear often in $X$. So just to make sure, you mean the first type of distribution?

Comment: You're right. These two are separate distributions. I am looking for the "uniformly sampled subsequence" type.

Comment: Why is there no dependency on $k$ in your conjecture? What regime of parameters are you interested in?

Comment: You're right again. I fixed it. $k=\Theta n$ for some constant $\Theta\in(0,1)$.